# Attribute value not found

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp

Hi I'm working with xml and jsp and I try to put a href in my code. Eclipse returns me a strage message. Can you help me with this code?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- <c:forEach var="number" items="${sessionScope.list}"> -->

    <c:forEach var="number" items="${requestScope.list}">
    <li>
        <a href="./es3?index=<c:out value='${number}'/>"> (*) </a>
    </li>   
        </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

And Eclipse gives me here (*) the error: 
    "- Attribute value * not closed."

I'm sorry for the indentation. If someone could help me solving the problem I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, simply, use this notation :

```
 <a href="./es3?index=${number}"> (*) </a>
```

Comment: Take attention to the quotes and do it like this if you really want to use c:out : <a href="./es3?index=<c:out value='${interface.id}'/>"> (*) </a>

Comment: You are right about the quotes and I'm sorry if the mistake is so stupid but what about the wrong closure of the foreach? I, obviously, have it in the code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see another problem. Can you paste your current code ?

Comment: It is exactly the same with your correction. I will put the update

Comment: I don't see it either but eclipse gives it as an error

Comment: Well ... It's your commented line which causes eclipse to show an error... Either remove it, use jsp comments <%-- --%> or remove the begin tag char ('<') as in '<!-- c:forEach var="number" items="${sessionScope.list}" -->'

Comment: I find the error. Thanks for the helping. It was the <ul> </ul> I forget to put, it's not the comment :)